# Javascript function not working. Script positioning issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-waypoints

I am attempting to get jQuery waypoints to work and I am doing a very basic example and it won't display the window alert that I am attempting to show when scrolled to. I was watching a video of this and I had exactly what the guy had, so I am not sure why it isn't working for me.

Any ideas of why this not initiating?

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
</head>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <section>
        <img src="images/big-smile-face.png" class="dipper" alt="">
    </section>
 <script src="js/waypoints.js"></script> <!-- js/waypoints.js file -->
```

Javascript - js/waypoints.js file

```
$(document ).ready(function(){
var $dipper = $('.dipper');

$dipper.waypoint(function () {
    alert('waypoint!');
});
});
```

Comment: Working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/q4vfdeyu/8/

Comment: @Rayon It doesn't work when I go to your fiddle, at least for me. It also doesn't work on my site.

Comment: Do test your fiddle.. Check console for errors...

Comment: I get this, but my fiddle I am not worried about, on my site I don't get any errors. `(index):51 Uncaught TypeError: $dipper.waypoint is not a function`

Comment: Check the provided fiddle.. You need to scroll down to get element in focus..

Comment: I know you have to scroll down. In your fiddle it doesn't work for me unless I have the console open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What browser are you using? There might be some issue there. It seems to be working fine for me and I am not getting any errors.

Comment: I've tried it in Chrome, Edge and just downloaded firefox and tried it there and doesn't work in any.

Comment: So one thing i notice is that if my browser height is too tall, the event never fires. The reason for this is that it looks like the script goes off when the image is at the very top of the browser. If your browser is stretched taller, the image never gets that far.

Comment: You are right!!! Wow, I have been beating my head up against a wall with this forever. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Good luck!